# Чистый SQL запрос в Yii2 с использованием модели унаследованной от yii\base\Model

Tags: sql, yii2, запрос, gridview

Здравствуйте.

Существует модель унаследованная от yii\base\Model. 
В ней есть функция, которая выполняет SQL запрос используя yii\db\Query и результат передает в GridView.

Но возникла необходимость написать более сложный запрос и придется использовать чистый SQL запрос в модели.

В документации приведен пример с Yii::$app->db->createCommand, но возвращается выборка в виде массива, что, в свою очередь, не подойдет для  GridView.

Вот есть что-то похожее на findBySql, что используется в моделях унаследованных от AcriveRecord?

Задача в том, чтобы был можно было вставить чистый SQL запрос и получит объект Query для отображения в GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для GridView можно использовать [ArrayDataProvider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider)

По поводу "чистого SQL". На билдере запросов можно построить любую конструкцию.

Comment: Можно уточнить про билдер, если не сложно, а то не понял о чем речь. )

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-dao.md  и https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-query-builder.md